# What is the density of $1-X^3$ if $X$ is a Cauchy random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the density function of $Y=1-X^3$, if $X$ is a Cauchy random variable?

My approach:
$$Pr(Y<y)=Pr(1-X^{3}<y)=Pr(X<(1-y)^{-3})=\int^{y}_{-\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{\pi(1+t^{2})}\right)^{-3}\:dt$$ - is this ok?

And then the density function would be the derivative of the function above?

EDIT1
$$Pr(Y<y)=Pr(1-X^{3}<y)=Pr(X>(1-y)^{-3})=1-\int^{(1-y)^{-3}}_{-\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\pi(1+t^{2})}\right)\:dt=1-A$$

The CDF for Cauchy distribution, according to Wikipedia [Cauchy Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) - do I use it correctly?

$$A=\frac{1}{\pi}arctan((1-y)^{-3})+\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}arctan(-\infty)-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{\pi}arctan((1-y)^{-3})-\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{-\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{\pi}arctan((1-y)^{-3})+\frac{1}{2}$$

Than the distribution function would be the derivative of 1-A ?

is this correct?

Comment: $1-X^3<y\Leftrightarrow X<(1-y)^{-3}$ is not true. The inequality on the right is not correct.

Comment: Avitus, it should have been > instead of <, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the problem mentioned by @Avitus in a comment, let me mention that the identity
$$
P(X\lt g(x))=\int_{-\infty}^xg(f_X(t))\mathrm dt,
$$
where $f_X$ is the density of $X$, is quite wrong. Please use the correct
$$
P(X\lt g(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{g(x)}f_X(t)\mathrm dt.
$$
When, as in your case, the function $g$ is increasing and differentiable, this is also
$$
P(X\lt g(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{x}g'(s)f_X(g(s))\mathrm ds.
$$
Likewise, if $g$ is decreasing and differentiable and $Y=g^{-1}(X)$, then
$$
P(Y\lt x)=P(X\gt g(x))=\int_{g(x)}^{+\infty}f_X(t)\mathrm dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x}(-g'(s))f_X(g(s))\mathrm ds.
$$

Comment: Thank you Did, could you also write the answer to the problem using the data in the question besides the general solution?That would really hep me understand it. I would appreciate your effort a lot! Thank you

Comment: What about showing instead how @Avitus' comment and my answer helped you make some steps towards solving the question? This way we would know what is still blocking you.

Comment: @Ryan Did is right: try to correct the inequality and the integral. It would be nice if you could add in your questions the computations you can write, before getting blocked.

Comment: I added an Edit. Can you please verify if i'm using a correct approach. Is the distribution function the derivative of what I have obtained as the value of 1-A?

Comment: Let me suggest to compare it to the (new) formula at the end of my post.

Comment: Thanks Did, I was thinking that since the primitive of fX is known, since fX is the Cauchy Distribution, it would be easier than to change the variable and compute a new integral. If you look at what I did in the EDIT, does it look correct to you?

Comment: Why one would first integrate the density $f_X$ and then derive the result escapes me, to tell you the truth. Using the formula $f_Y(x)=-g'(x)f_X(g(x))$ reached in my post seems much simpler and much less error-prone, no?